# Capitalizing armory

Tags: grammar

I believe if referring to a specific armory in a specific city, that would be capitalized but what if it just says National Guard Armory? Would that also be capitalized or would it be National Guard armory? Thank you.

Comment: It's a little tricky.  It's an armory that belongs to the National Guard, but it may or may not be *named* "National Guard Armory".  (It may be, eg, the "General William F. Smith Armory" or the "East Podunk Armory".)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that if it's a specific place, then "armory" would be capitalized. However, if it's generic place or description, then it would not be capitalized. Similar to saying "Let's go to a Chinese restaurant" vs. "Let's go to the Chinese Restaurant"--assuming the place is named Chinese Restaurant :).